# Example of C/C++ app wrapped in Android JNI and iOS

Tags: android, c++, ios, c, java-native-interface

I am looking for an example of C/C++ app that uses the same code to run on Android via JNI and iOS

Ideally some kind of open source github project that I can pick apart, or maybe something part of a tutorial

hoping the collective conscious can at least guide me in the right direction here. we can ask for examples right?

Comment: It's not that complicated. Write C/C++ standard code, compile it, and bridge it to the host environments.

Comment: @Linuxios I wanted to see something complex and graphical like an open gl environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments you mention wanting something graphical.  Check out [Cocos2D-X](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/), a C++ game engine with various implementations (iOS and Android being two).